# Dell PowerEdge R710 direct-attached to HP MSA 2040 SAN

Tags: storage, hp, storage-area-network, fibre-channel

I have no idea about Direct attached storage; I do not know that it is possible to do.
I plan to use HP MSA 2040 storage to direct attached with my dell Power Edge R710 via Fiber Channel.

What do i need to set up? Is there are some card to connect between storage and server via FC?

Comment: For starters you'll need a Fiber Channel Host Bus Adapter (FC HBA) in the server. My suggestion would be that you talk to your Dell rep to find out what FC HBA's are available and compatible with your server. Something like this probably - http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dell.com%2Fdownloads%2Fglobal%2Fproducts%2Fpwcnt%2Fen%2Fswitch-brocade-815-825-specsheet.pdf&ei=WdCXU8rLEY6dyATe5oDoCw&usg=AFQjCNGBCoWtDqXFtLi_s3sAcyESaRSSkg&sig2=nLe-8u7s9MaXEuHqnsv-_A

Comment: i plan to set up SAN switch with HP MSA 2040 and will buy more HP dl380 server in the future So i want to use Fiber for now and it will be ready for next level iplementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a choice, I'd recommend an [HP MSA2040 *SAS* unit](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/disk-storage/product-detail.html?oid=5386548#!tab=features) if you only plan to connect to *one* server. It's a simpler and more effective connection option. Otherwise, this is probably the wrong product for you.

[Please read the HP StorageWorks MSA 2040 QuickSpecs guide here](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14603_na/14603_na.pdf).

If you wish to use fiber channel, you have two options: 8Gb and 16Gb SFPs. The MSA 2040 requires that these be purchased in a pack of four; part numbers *C8R23A* and *C8R24A*, respectively.

You will then need fiber cables and of course, an appropriate HBA for your server; HP parts *QR558A*, *QR559A*, *AJ762B* and *AJ763B* are examples, but most anything will work.

But in the end, this is basic *read-the-manual* level stuff. If you're unsure, lean on your vendor as a resource to help you make a better decision about your specific environment. This is a relatively expensive enclosure, and the SFP modules and HBA cards are costly as well. Why risk it?

Comment: +1 - if you're asking these questions, then an FC unit is wrong for you. Go with the SAS unit for lower cost and simplified installation at the cost of potential host expansion.